# How to load google charts with frozen library?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, jsapi

Normally the google charts library is loaded as follows, which works fine:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(v);
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(elm[0]);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Now I want to switch to a frozen version of the corecharts. The docs state this is to be done as follows:

```
google.charts.load('41', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

@see https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/library_loading_enhancements

Problem: 
Using this, I'm getting the error in javascript that `google.visualization` is not defined.

So, how do I have to load the frozen version?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the loading, the issue is the moment when you access `google.visualization`.

The documentation states that you should supply a callback for `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback` where you create the chart, but you don't.

As it seems the scripts will be loaded synchronously (via `document.write` ) when you load the library normally, but when you load the frozen version the scripts will be loaded asynchronously(via `appendChild`), that's why your attempt fails(the scripts have not been loaded completely when you try to access `google.visualization`)

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the source of script tag ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```